# WSP solution not working properly in NLB environment

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, solution-package, wspbuilder

We have one exisiting SharePoint project which was created few years ago. Now we have updated the code and created a WSP solution. After deploying the WSP solution in the development environment (which is not NLB configured) it's working fine.

But, when we pushed this WSP solution to production environment (which is NLB configured), we are facing some issues: All the URLs are going into one server only not the other.

Let's say:

- We have two servers `A` & `B` configured in NLB in production environment.
- After the solution is deployed, all the websites are hitting only to server `A` nothing goes to `B`.

Any help in this regard?

**Notes**

- We have build the solution and created the WSP solution from the development environment only.
- While creating the WSP solution, we provided siteURL as our develeopment url. Does this have any impact over WSP solution like?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check.

- what is the status of NLB without the WSP deployment. was traffic routing both server? I am guessing your problem is at NLB level
- Make sure your DNS pointing to NLB( nlb having both server in it).

But you should also make sure WSP deployment completed sucessfully.

- from central admin > system settings > Manage Farm Solution> over here click on your wsp and make sure it deployed to all servers.
- Also make sure SharePoint admin and timer services is running on all server.
- make sure the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application " on both Web front end.